# Dynamically setFieldValue to group of checkboxes in formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, formik-material-ui

**MY Problem**
I am trying the set the field values to the group of checkboxes using the `formik.setFieldValue` property. These values are coming from a backend API in the form of an array.

**My Code**
I am using the useFormik hook of the formik library to handle checkbox values. I have set up the `formik.handleChange` on my checkboxes onChange function.  Here is the bare minimum code snippet of my application.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";



const tags = ["one", "two", "three"];

const ProjectsForm = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,
    initialValues: {
      tags: []
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
    }
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
      {tags.map((tag) => (
        <div key={tag}>
          <input
            id={tag}
            type="checkbox"
            name={tag}
            
            onChange={formik.handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor={tag}>{tag}</label>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

How do I use the `formik.setFieldValue` to set the value to my checkboxes coming from the backend?

Comment: can you add the data schema you are receiving from API in the question? Also when you click submit how you want your `values` object to look like? Are the checkbox values the part of tags array?